# Generate string of only file names from directory/subdirectory in Python, no directory address

Tags: python, list, file, directory, pathlib

NOTE: SEE EDITED VERSION OF QUESTION AT THE BOTTOM RE USING pathlib

I would like to iterate through directory/subdirectories (Mac) and list all filenames as a string. I can do this fine but the string includes directory info, eg /Users/TK/Downloads/Temp/a_c/imgs_a/a1.tif

I just want the "a1.tif".

Here's my code

```
'''
    For the given path, get the List of all files in the directory tree
'''

import os
def getListOfFiles(dirName):
    # create a list of file and sub directories
    # names in the given directory
    listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
    allFiles = list()
    # Iterate over all the entries
    for entry in listOfFile:
        # Create full path
        fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
        # If entry is a directory then get the list of files in this directory
        if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
            allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
        else:
            allFiles.append(fullPath)

    return allFiles

dirName = "/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c";
# Get the list of all files in directory tree at given path
listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)
file_string = str(sorted(listOfFiles))
print(file_string)
```

How do I get rid of the directory info and just list the file name (without extension even better)

--CHANGE OF CODE AS PER BELOW SUGGESTIONS--
--IT WORKS WITH A FEW SMALL ISSUES--

```
from pathlib import Path

path = os.chdir("/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c")

path = Path.cwd()

files = []
for file in path.rglob('*'):  # loop recursively over all subdirectories
    files.append(file.name)

files = [file.stem for file in path.rglob('*')]

fileList = str(sorted(files))
print(fileList)
```

The result is ['.DS_Store', '.DS_Store', '.tif', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'imgs_a', 'imgs_b', 'imgs_c']

Almost perfect - can I get rid of everything but 'a1', 'a2'...'c6'

Also I couldn't place the dir into `path = Path.cwd()` which is why I used `path = os.chdir("/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c")`

-------------Edited Question------------

I like the idea of using pathlib as suggested below. From what I've researched online, it seems to be simplest version of code to get the job done and it should work? But somehow it's not giving me what I'm after.

pathlib code I've tried

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c')
files = [file.stem for file in path.rglob('*')]
print(files)
```

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path('/Users/TalaKaplinovsky/Downloads/Patrick_Strips_Temp_Folder/a_c')stem)
```

Both give me this
Output identical for both versions:
'/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c/.DS_Store', '/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c/imgs_b/b2.tif'
'/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c/imgs_b/b3.tif', '/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c/imgs_b/b1.tif',
'/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c/imgs_a/.tif',
'/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c/imgs_a/a4.tif',

I just want 'b2', 'b3', 'b1', 'a4' and sorted in an order (a4, b1, etc)

Comment: What do you mean by 'getting rid of everything except a1 - c6'? What is the pattern that defines a legal file? Just a letter followed by a digit?

Comment: yes, the files were named 'a1.tif, a2.tif etc'. But I resolved it. See my answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this fairly simple by using `pathlib` (comes bundled with python):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path.cwd()  # insert your path 

files = []
for file in path.rglob('*'):  # loop recursively over all subdirectories
    files.append(file.name)
```

or, even simpler:

```py
files = [file.name for file in path.rglob('*')]
```

To remove the extension, you can use `Path.stem`:

```py
files = [file.stem for file in path.rglob('*')]
```

Comment: I'm liking the idea of pathlib but somehow it's not giving me what I want. Tried two varieties fo code but keep getting the same result: see edited question above

Comment: That is weird because for me it works as expected... What python version are you using? Oh and the `Path.cwd()` was only an example, you should just insert your own path instead

Comment: thanks very much, yes I was doing silly things - it works, see my answer below. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = '/home/User/Documents/file.txt'
basename = os.path.basename(path)

# Print the basename name 
print(basename)

filename = basename.split(".")[0]
print(filename)
```

From this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-basename-method/

Edited suggestion below

```
fileList = ['.DS_Store', '.DS_Store', '.tif', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', '    b6', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'imgs_a', 'imgs_b', 'imgs_c']

new_result = [c for c in fileList if len(c)<3]
print(new_result)
```

Comment: This generates only the names of the subfolders (?). Output is [a_c
a_c]. Should be as listed in my edited question above...

Comment: Yes, as you've edited this is my suggestion, there are many ways to do this, but if the file names doesn't change every time, you can use the edited above code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - silly me - pathlib does work, I was running the wrong window.
This code is working!!

Read file names in a directory and subdirectories, print out list of only file names (no directory listing) in sorted format.

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c')
files = [file.stem for file in path.rglob('*')]
print(sorted(files))
```

Output:
`['.DS_Store', '.DS_Store', '.tif', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'imgs_a', 'imgs_b', 'imgs_c']`

Note - this also returns the folders in directory 'imgs_a' etc;
and hidden files '.DS_Store';
and something called '.tif' which is not an actual file

To only get the 'a1', 'a2' etc (which are all .tif files), I did this:

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/Users/TK/Downloads/Temp_Folder/a_c')
files = [file.stem for file in path.rglob('*.tif')] #select only '.tif' files
files.remove(".tif") #remove the unwanted '.tif' file
print(sorted(files))
```

Output:
`['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'a6', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6']`

Everything I didn't need is now gone and only the actual tif files are listed, without the extension